# Unreasonable errors in merge sort

Tags: c

i have the following errors - please help me to find the error:

```
9   IntelliSense: expected a '}'        70  4
```

it points on the end of the code - but there are no open { anywhere!! so why??

```
8   IntelliSense: expected a ';'        57  1
```

it points on the { after the void main but why to put ; after the { of the void main??

```
Error   7   error C1075: end of file found before the left brace '{' at     70  1
```

points to the beginig of the code - why???

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void merge(int *a,int p,int q,int r)
{
  int i=p,j=q+1,k=0;
  int* temp=(int*)calloc(r-p+1, sizeof(int));
  while ((i<=q)&& (j<=r))
        if(a[i]<a[j])
                    temp[k++]=a[i++];
        else 
                    temp[k++]=a[j++];
  while(j<=r)   // if( i>q )
    temp[k++]=a[j++];
 while(i<=q)   //  j>r 
    temp[k++]=a[i++];

  for(i=p,k=0;i<=r;i++,k++)   //  copy temp[] to a[]   
            a[i]=temp[k];
  free(temp);
}

void merge_sort(int *a,int first, int last)
{
     int middle;
            if(first < last)
           {
                middle=(first+last)/2;
                merge_sort(a,first,middle);
                merge_sort(a,middle+1,last);
                merge(a,first,middle,last);
           {
}

void main()
{

    int a[] = {9, 7, 2, 3, 5, 4, 1, 8, 6, 10};
    int i;

    merge_sort(a, 0, 9);

    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        printf ("%d ", a[i]);
```

Comment: Just use braces at all times and spare yourself errors like these.  You're just lucky this one is a compile time error.

Comment: Perhaps use an editor that indents your code for you?

Comment: Why did you change the bad code in the question? That's obviously what the problem was and now you've basically made the Q and As irrelevant. Changing it back, pending an explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You braces don't match here.

```
if(first < last)
 {
      middle=(first+last)/2;
      merge_sort(a,first,middle);
      merge_sort(a,middle+1,last);
      merge(a,first,middle,last);
 {
```

Answer (score 2):

Here

```
            if(first < last)
       {
            middle=(first+last)/2;
            merge_sort(a,first,middle);
            merge_sort(a,middle+1,last);
            merge(a,first,middle,last);
       {
```

you're not closing the brace, but opening a second layer. Fix that and xour indentation, and a lot of errors will magically disappear.

Answer (score 0):

The closing brace of the `if(first < last)` block is an opening brace, not a closing brace. That's you error.

Answer (score 0):

your correct version :

also to avoid(warning: return type of ‘main’ is not ‘int’)
you should change void to int and use return 0; in the end of main.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void merge(int *a, int p, int q, int r) {
int i = p, j = q + 1, k = 0;
int* temp = (int*) calloc(r - p + 1, sizeof(int));
while ((i <= q) && (j <= r))
    if (a[i] < a[j])
        temp[k++] = a[i++];
    else
        temp[k++] = a[j++];
while (j <= r) // if( i>q )
    temp[k++] = a[j++];
while (i <= q) //  j>r
    temp[k++] = a[i++];

for (i = p, k = 0; i <= r; i++, k++) //  copy temp[] to a[]
    a[i] = temp[k];
free(temp);
}

void merge_sort(int *a, int first, int last) {
int middle;
if (first < last) {
    middle = (first + last) / 2;
    merge_sort(a, first, middle);
    merge_sort(a, middle + 1, last);
    merge(a, first, middle, last);
}
}
int main(int argc,char* argv[]) {

int a[] = { 9, 7, 2, 3, 5, 4, 1, 8, 6, 10 };
int i;

merge_sort(a, 0, 9);

for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    printf("%d ", a[i]);

return 0;

}
```